# Timeout expired while starting chaincode error when instantiating chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I run the example here: [fabric e2e examples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/examples/e2e_cli) it fails at instantiating chaincode. You can see a screenshot here of the error:

[image]

I can see that the chaincode instance/container was started but exited shortly after.

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to resolve?

Comment: Can you get the logs for the chaincode container which exited?
For example:  "docker logs 0d893fb03bc6" (that's the container ID from the image you attached)

Comment: @GariSingh Yes, I see this:   2017-11-30 14:25:51.519 UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 001 Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded
Error starting Simple chaincode: Error trying to connect to local peer: context deadline exceeded%

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while testing fabric-samples balance-transfer and fabcar samples, and fabric PTE testing.

Solved it by setting `CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS` to peer's `containername:port` in the docker compose file.

eg., `CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052`

Issue: Chaincode container (which gets created and killed after certain time) log shows below error, when inspected with `docker logs CONTAINER-ID`.

```
UTC [shim] userChaincodeStreamGetter -> ERRO 001 x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.18.0.5 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
error trying to connect to local peer
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.userChaincodeStreamGetter
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:109
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:148
main.main
    /chaincode/input/src/github.com/example_cc/go/example_cc.go:199
runtime.main
    /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:185
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
2017-12-26 09:59:52.823 UTC [example_cc0] Errorf -> ERRO 002 Error starting Simple chaincode: error trying to connect to local peer: x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.18.0.5 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```